# "List name - View name" shows up on top of list

Tags: 2010, list, list-view

I have a really weird issue where my list name and view name show up on top of list. The view in question is All Items and it has been modified by me. This is how the List looks.

[image]

On viewing the source I see something like:

```
<div id="ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv">
   <a name="mainContent"></a>
   <LIST_NAME> - All Items
   <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<LIST_NAME>" ...
```

I cannot figure out where this text is coming from and I cannot find any setting to turn this text off. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple solution to get around this problem.

Go to "List Settings", create a new view based on the current (problematic) view. Make that view default. Now in your newly created view, you wont see the view title on top. Delete the old view and you are done.

Comment: Great! If you still have a copy of that old list, you may want to check the schema.xml for that problematic view definition!

Comment: @VamsiKK: Nope... :( Deleted the old view in excitement...!

Comment: :) ya! I can imagine that excitement!